# Selenium+Рython: как задать имя скачиваемого файла

Tags: python, selenium

Начал осваивать Selenium. Нужна помощь в скачивании файлов. В общем виде задача такая: мне нужно дойти до кнопки выгрузки отчета, нажать на эту кнопку, после чего скачивается файл. Код конечной кнопки для скачивания выглядит так:

[Пример кода](https://yadi.sk/i/vj4EwZRdZakUXg)

Нажимаю на кнопку так:

```
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="popup-window-content-stexport_lead_manager_r4ilewsylk_lrpdlg"]/div/div[1]/a')

ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click().perform()
```

Код отрабатывает хорошо, файл скачивается. Проблема в другом - каждый раз система меняет имя файла для скачивания. А мне нужно скачивать всегда с одним именем, или в крайнем случае получать имя файла, который сейчас скачался. Подскажите как реализовать один из этих сценариев, т.к. моих знаний в Selenium пока ен хватает для решения.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56570364/5909792

Answer (score 1):

Вы не можете указать имя загружаемого файла через Selenium.
Но можно после загрузки, найти этот файл и переименовать.

З.Ы.: найденные способы из Google могут содержать ошибки.

```
import os
import shutil
filename = max([Initial_path + "\\" + f for f in os.listdir(Initial_path)],key=os.path.getctime)
shutil.move(filename,os.path.join(Initial_path,r"newfilename.ext"))
```

Comment: А что за `Initial_path`?

Comment: путь к файлу же

Comment: Судя по коду, это путь не к файлу, а к папке (вопрос к какой?). Да и все-равно не понятно как это поможет

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо, вопрос снимается.
Решил следующим образом:

1. через .get_attribute("href") получил урл
2. регулярным выражением из урла вытащил название файла.
3. открыл документ по значению регулярного выражения pd.read_csv('C:\Users\Dima\Downloads\%s.csv' % opendoc, sep=';', encoding='utf-8')
4. такой же конструкцией удалил файл после сбора информации.